# configuring properties for dependent artifacts from inside a war

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, java-8, war

I'm writing a jee app deployed as a WAR to a container.

This app depends (maven dep) on a java lib packaged as a JAR.

The lib contains a client used by the jee app to talk to a backend.

The lib accepts the base uri of the backend (host+port+context-path) as a configuration.

**What is the best way to configure the lib from the jee app** so that one can provide configuration for multiple environments (e.g. backend production URI is different from test URI)?

I read about @Alternative annotation and ContextParam, but both seem jee specific AKA not understood by plain java...

Maven Assembly does not seem the way to go as it would imply having to deploy to our maven repo one artifact per environment.

**UPDATE 1**

What if the jee app contains one properties file per environment (dev, test, prod) and can pass the properties down to the lib via plain old java constructor?

Comment: So, are you looking for a non-JEE-way of configuring a JEE-application? Question 2: How is the base URI passed to the lib? Does it maybe provide own ways of configuration? Or is it Java-based?

Comment: I'd say that I'm looking for a way to provide configuration that us understood by both plain old Java and jee. I am the author of both the lib and the war, so I can change them as needed. ATM the lib is configured via a prop file embedded in the jar, but this is not flexible enough as different deployments of the client war need to be able to provide different configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and provide some answers / ideas to the topic. I would follow this approach:

- Provide a fallback configuration file in the library.
- Implement a default behavior in the library that looks for a predefined configuration file on the classpath which has higher precedence than the fallback (e.g. via `java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`)
- Let the library provide a Java-API to read the configuration from a different location / ressource.
- Let the library provide a Java-API to change specific configuration settings directly from client code.
- You could also provide the possibility to configure your library via system environment variables and / or command line parameters.

This way, clients of the library can decide where the configuration resides, dependent on their technical landscape.

In JEE you could then use a ContextParam to set the location of the configuration resource, or to set specific configuration properties, or just provide a configuration resource in the standard location on the classpath.

If you use Spring or similar frameworks, you have loads of other possibilities to provide configuration to an application. Spring Boot provides some nice behavior out-of-the-box regarding this.

Underlying idea is that you have to provide means to the operator of the application to influence the configuration. Then it is possible to adapt configuration according to whether it is run on a developer's machine, in unit / integration testing conditions, in a staging environment or in production.

Comment: Thank you Lars. I was imagining a similar solution. Yesterday I implemented one following your approach; my clients hold a properties file per environment to configure the lib. Inside the lib I read the appropriate properties file fromt the classpath based on the environment variable.